# Representation of the full ring of $n\times n$ matrices

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

I am now reading the book 'representations of groups' by Boerner.

On page 72, he states the theorem: Every representation of $M_n$ is completely reducible; every irreducible representation is equivalent to $M_n$. Here $M_n$ denotes the full ring of $n\times n $ matrices.

It seems that the theorem does not hold for the general linear group, namely for the non-singular $n\times n $ matrices.

Is this true? If so, why?

Answer (score 3):

A representation of $M_n$ as an algebra has to preserve the matrix multiplication as well as the addition of matrices.

A representation of the general linear group only needs to preserve the multiplication, and in general will not preserve addition of matrices.

For example taking determinants gives a 1 dimensional representation of $GL(n)$ since $det(AB)=det(A)det(B)$, but it is not a representation of $M_n$ since in general $det(A+B)\ne det(A)+det(B)$.

Representations of a group *are* the same thing as modules over their group algebra but the group algebra of $GL(n)$ is **not** $M_n$. (Moreover for $GL(n)$ we generally only consider `nice' classes of representations such as algebraic or continuous ones, but that's another topic all together)